# Extract values of given keys that are inside a string in python

Tags: python, regex

```
'2019-01-04T03:22:17.950795+00:00 CONSOLE:0 (null) - 01-04-2019 03:22:17.950 INFO (SGUI.APP) - report_event:{"event":"pip-started", "time":"110ms"}#012'
```

From this my aim is to extract 'pip-started' and '110' using 'event' and 'time' as keys to identify value

Comment: plz provide some more information about the code or task

Comment: Please show us what you have tried before asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This expression might likely extract those values:

```
import re

regex = r"\"event\":\"([^\"]+)\"|\"time\":\"(\d+)"
test_str = "2019-01-04T03:22:17.950795+00:00 CONSOLE:0 (null) - 01-04-2019 03:22:17.950 INFO (SGUI.APP) - report_event:{\"event\":\"pip-started\", \"time\":\"110ms\"}#012"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
[('pip-started', ''), ('', '110')]
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7IMFkF/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/7IMFkF/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import json

string = '2019-01-04T03:22:17.950795+00:00 CONSOLE:0 (null) - 01-04-2019 03:22:17.950 INFO (SGUI.APP) - report_event:{"event":"pip-started", "time":"110ms"}#012'

extract = re.findall(r'\{.*\}', string)

json.loads(extract[0]).get('event')
json.loads(extract[0]).get('time')
```

output:

```
 'pip-started'
 '110ms'
```

json.loads can be used to create a dictionary from a string. Once you have the dictionary, use get to acquire the values.